# How to get the abstract class name from child class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have few models as below,

```
class FooBarAbstract(models.Model):
    foobar = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Foo(FooBarAbstract):
    foo = models.IntegerField()


class Bar(FooBarAbstract):
    bar = models.IntegerField()
```

How can I get the abstract class name (`FooBarAbstract`) by using child classes (`Foo` or `Bar` ) or their objects?

Comment: Try .mro() ? (Method resolution Order)

Comment: @VineethSai Partially it does the job by returning a `tuple`. But, I need a string

Comment: @JPG You can get to the name via the `.__name__` attribute of the tuple elements. But maybe, you can elaborate what you need this for? Possibly there is a better approach.

Comment: What if there are multiple (abstract) models from which the model inherits? Do we count indirect inheritance (a model inherited by a model that is inherited by `Bar`) as well?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem There is only *one abstract class* from which the model inherits. But, there may be a possibility for **Multiple Inheritance**

Comment: Well it is perfectly possible to let a model inherit from multiple abstract models (thorugh indirect inheritance, or multiple inheritance). Therefore I think it is advissable to specify what should happen in these cases.

Comment: I think I should consider those things, but now I'm not digging that much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the names of the base classes of a class from the class' [`__bases__`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__) attribute.

Assuming your derived classes always inherit from only one class, you can use the following to obtain the name of the base class:

```
class Foo(FooBarAbstract):
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__class__.__bases__[0].__name__)
```

so that `Foo()` would output: `FooBarAbstract`

Note that the `mro` method and the `__mro__` attribute are less suited to your purpose because they contain not just the parent class but also the current class, and the parent class of the parent class, so you would have to skip over them before you can obtain the parent class.

Answer (score 2):

By using python `__bases__` it will return a tuple of base class names:

```
class Foo():
    pass

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

bb = Bar
bb.__bases__[0].__name__
# 'Foo'
```

But I don't know is there any additional way in django to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, This is an example and you can change the index according to Django hierarchy.

```
class Foo():
    pass

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

class Eggs(Foo):
    pass
```

Now for Eggs class

`Eggs.mro()[-2].__name__   # change your index accordingly to your class inheritance structure.`

> Returns Foo

for info:

Django's abstract class are just to make sure that they don't create an extra table in the database.